# Create a Default page without sidebar and route

Tags: reactjs

Goal:
Show the first page (default page) that contain a button that goes to the page with sidebar link Home and About using Router.

Problem:
Today, you have a menu with link Home and About but if I want a default page (that is the main page that you enter) and then you go to another page that has sidebar and using route.

How should it be created?

Info:
*Newbie in Reactjs
*The main page (default) should not contain any sidebar or any route.

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-k19hye?

---

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Nav = () => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
);

const HomePage = () => <h1>Home Page</h1>;
const AboutPage = () => <h1>About Page</h1>;

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        {/* Router component can have only 1 child. We'll use a simple
          div element for this example. */}
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set another default page, you should first update the route to `HomePage` to `/home`. And then define another route for the `DefaultPage` like `<Route exact path="/" component={DefaultPage} />`. In order to hide sidebar on the `DefaultPage`, you can use [`Switch`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) to show only `DefaultPage` on route `/`.

You can take a look at [this updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ajkyu5) forked from your original example for a live working example. Here is the final full code of this usage:

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch,
  useHistory,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const Nav = () => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
);

const DefaultPage = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Default Page</h1>
      <button onClick={() => history.push('/main')}>go to main</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const HomePage = () => <h1>Home Page</h1>;
const AboutPage = () => <h1>About Page</h1>;

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          {/* Router component can have only 1 child. We'll use a simple
            div element for this example. */}
          <Route exact path="/" component={DefaultPage} />
          <div>
            <Nav />
            <Route exact path="/home" component={HomePage} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
          </div>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I was enable to write 'https://react-jmrfcq.stackblitz.io/mmmmmain' and then entoer the page there you could see sidebar etc. Is itpossible to specify a specific name for instance ''mainindex' and if it not exist a errror page should display?
Thank you!